# Nested class template orginization

Tags: c++, templates

I an working on a doubly linked list class. I have implemented a Node class that contains a pointer to the next element and a pointer to the previous element as well as a data section (with type defined by the template parameter 'Type')

Initially, I implemented this as two classes. One class defined a Node, and the other defined the linked list of nodes (rList). I wanted to include the Node class template as a private member of the rList as Nodes should be hidden within the list and managed only by rlist.

The Node class only has a constructor that initializes the data section and sets the pointers to null.

I have tried to put the Node class in the private section of the rList class, but I cant seem to get the organization correct. I get plauged with syntax errors. Below is my current implementation.

```
template<typename Type>
class Node
{
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;

public:
    Node(Type);
    template<typename Type> friend class rList;
    Type data;
};

template<typename Type>
Node<Type>::Node(Type d):data(d), next(0), prev(0)
{}


template<typename Type>
class rList
{
private:
    Node<Type>* head;
    Node<Type>* tail;
    int size;

public:

    rList<Type>();
    ~rList();
    void push_front(const Type&);
    void push_back(const Type&);
    void insert(Node<Type>*, const Type&); //needs to be changed after merge
    void erase(Node<Type>*); //needs to be changed after merge
    void clear();
};

template<typename Type>
rList<Type>::rList():head(0), tail(0), size(0)
{}


template<typename Type>
rList<Type>::~rList()
{
    clear();
}


template<typename Type>
void rList<Type>::clear()
{
    while(head != 0)
    {
        Node<Type>* nextNode = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = nextNode;
    }
}


template<typename Type>
void rList<Type>::push_front(const Type& data)
{
    Node<Type>* newOne = new Node<Type>(data);

    if(head == 0)
    {
        head = newOne;
        tail = head;
    }
    else
    {
        newOne->next = head;
        head = newOne;
    }
    size++;
}


template<typename Type>
void rList<Type>::push_back(const Type& data)
{
    Node<Type>* newOne = new Node<Type>(data);

    if(head == 0)
    {
        head = newOne;
        tail = head;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = newOne;
        newOne->prev = tail; 
        tail = newOne;
    }
    size++;
}


template<typename Type>
void rList<Type>::insert(Node<Type>* itr, const Type& data)
{
    Node<Type>* newOne = new Node<Type>(data);

    if(head == 0)
    {
        head = newOne;
        tail = head;
    }
    else 
    {   
        newOne->next = itr;
        (itr->prev)->next = newOne;
        newOne->prev = itr->prev;
        itr->prev = newOne;
    }
    size++;
}


template<typename Type>
void rList<Type>::erase(Node<Type>* itr)
{
    if(itr == tail)
    {
        tail = itr->prev;
        tail->next = 0;
        delete itr;
    }

    else if(itr == head)
    {
        head = itr->next;
        head->prev = 0;
        delete itr;
    }

    else
    {
        (itr->prev)->next = itr->next;
        (itr->next)->prev = itr->prev;
        delete itr;
    }
    size--;
}


template<typename Type>
Node<Type>* rList<Type>::begin()
{
    return head;
}


template<typename Type>
Node<Type>* rList<Type>::end()
{
    return tail;
}


template<typename Type>
Node<Type>* rList<Type>::nextElem(Node<Type>* node)
{
    return node->next;
}
```

I realize that this will breaks some things as Node*'s cannot be defined outside the rList class. I am planning on changing this later with an iterator class to access the Nodes in the rList. But first, how would one organize the templates and member function definitions with this type of arrangement? Below shows my attempt:

```
template<typename Type>
class rList //rList class template
{
private:
    template<typename Type>
    class Node //Node class template
    {
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;

    public:
        Type data; //can be any POD type or class/struct
        Node(Type);
        template<typename Type> friend class rList; //so rList can access private Node pointers
    };
    Node<Type>* head;
    Node<Type>* tail;
    int size;

public:
    rList<Type>();
    ~rList();
    void push_front(const Type&);
    void push_back(const Type&);
    void insert(Node<Type>*, const Type&);
    void erase(Node<Type>*);
    clear();
};

template<typename Type>
rList<Type>::rList():head(0), tail(0), size(0)
{}


template<typename Type>
rList<Type>::~rList()
{
    clear();
}

template<typename Type>
void rList<Type>::clear()
{
    while(head != 0)
    {
        Node<Type>* nextNode = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = nextNode;
    }
}

template<typename Type>
void rList<Type>::push_front(const Type& data)
{
    Node<Type>* newOne = new Node<Type>(data);

    if(head == 0)
    {
        head = newOne;
        tail = head;
    }
    else
    {
        newOne->next = head;
        head = newOne;
    }
    size++;
}

template<typename Type>
void rList<Type>::push_back(const Type& data)
{
    Node<Type>* newOne = new Node<Type>(data);

    if(head == 0)
    {
        head = newOne;
        tail = head;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = newOne;
        newOne->prev = tail; 
        tail = newOne;
    }
    size++;
}

template<typename Type>
void rList<Type>::insert(Node<Type>* itr, const Type& data)
{
    Node<Type>* newOne = new Node<Type>(data);

    if(head == 0)
    {
        head = newOne;
        tail = head;
    }
    else 
    {   
        newOne->next = itr;
        (itr->prev)->next = newOne;
        newOne->prev = itr->prev;
        itr->prev = newOne;
    }
    size++;
}


template<typename Type>
void rList<Type>::erase(Node<Type>* itr)
{
    if(itr == tail)
    {
        tail = itr->prev;
        tail->next = 0;
        delete itr;
    }

    else if(itr == head)
    {
        head = itr->next;
        head->prev = 0;
        delete itr;
    }

    else
    {
        (itr->prev)->next = itr->next;
        (itr->next)->prev = itr->prev;
        delete itr;
    }
    size--;
}


//constructor for Node
template<typename Type>
rList<Type>::Node<Type>::Node(Type d):data(d), next(0), prev(0)
{}
```

I appreciate your input!

*** UPDATE CODE ***
The code below was modified based on the suggestions. It is working and appears to be hiding the appropriate members. Please comment on any improvements that you notice!
Thanks again!!

```
template<typename Type>
class rList
{
private:

    class Node
    {
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;

    public:
        Type data;
        Node(Type d);
        template<typename Type> friend class rList;
    };

    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int size;

public:
    rList<Type>();
    ~rList();
    void push_front(const Type&);
    void push_back(const Type&);
    void insert(Node*, const Type&);
    void erase(Node*);
    void clear();
};

template<typename Type>
rList<Type>::rList():head(0), tail(0), size(0)
{}


template<typename Type>
rList<Type>::~rList()
{
    clear();
}

template<typename Type>
void rList<Type>::clear()
{
    while(head != 0)
    {
        Node* nextNode = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = nextNode;
    }
}

template<typename Type>
void rList<Type>::push_front(const Type& data)
{
    Node* newOne = new Node(data);

    if(head == 0)
    {
        head = newOne;
        tail = head;
    }
    else
    {
        newOne->next = head;
        head = newOne;
    }
    size++;
}

template<typename Type>
void rList<Type>::push_back(const Type& data)
{
    Node* newOne = new Node(data);

    if(head == 0)
    {
        head = newOne;
        tail = head;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = newOne;
        newOne->prev = tail; 
        tail = newOne;
    }
    size++;
}

template<typename Type>
void rList<Type>::insert(Node* itr, const Type& data)
{
    Node* newOne = new Node(data);

    if(head == 0)
    {
        head = newOne;
        tail = head;
    }
    else 
    {   
        newOne->next = itr;
        (itr->prev)->next = newOne;
        newOne->prev = itr->prev;
        itr->prev = newOne;
    }
    size++;
}


template<typename Type>
void rList<Type>::erase(Node* itr)
{
    if(itr == tail)
    {
        tail = itr->prev;
        tail->next = 0;
        delete itr;
    }

    else if(itr == head)
    {
        head = itr->next;
        head->prev = 0;
        delete itr;
    }

    else
    {
        (itr->prev)->next = itr->next;
        (itr->next)->prev = itr->prev;
        delete itr;
    }
    size--;
}

template<typename Type>
rList<Type>::Node::Node(Type d):data(d), next(0), prev(0)
{}
```

Comment: Why not just use the STL linked list?

Comment: One of the requirements of this project is that STL code cannot be used. So I am writing my own simplified class, and learning a lot at the same time!

Comment: Than you should definitely make Node a private member class of rList<Type>. Without seeing your implementation you had before, its hard to say what you were doing wrong. However, I would just make sure that node is not a template (T is already defined in rList) and that your definitions are `template <typename T> rList<T>::Node::Node(T val){...}`.

Comment: Use a forward declaration for `Node<Type>` to refer to it from other classes: `template<typename Type> class Node;`   Also use `Node<Type>*` as type for the next/previous members in the `Node` template class.

Comment: @g-makulik I think the "correct" implementation would never expose the Node* (cuz you could never really tell who owns it, especially witout smart pointers).

Comment: Im not sure I understand. Doesnt Node have to be a template to support the 'data' variable type definition? rList and Node both have to be a template, right?

Comment: @radensb If node is a class nested in rList<T>, than it is not a template itself: it is of type rList<T>::Node, and thus has T available from Node<T>. It is part of a template class declaration, so the definitions get a little wonky, but what you want is `template <typename T> class rList{class Node{T Value; ...};};`

Comment: @MadScienceDreams I agree! Just meant for syntactical correctness ...